# open pdf file saved inside res/raw directory with external app android

Tags: android, pdf, inputstream, private

I have put a pdf file inside my app `raw/my_pdf.pdf` to prevent to be copied  and want to open it with external app in my tablet

here is what I tried :

```
public  void loadDocInReader(View v)
            throws ActivityNotFoundException, Exception {

        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setPackage("com.foobnix.pro.pdf.reader");
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("raw/my_pdf.pdf"), "application/pdf");

          startActivity(intent);

        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException) {
            activityNotFoundException.printStackTrace();

            throw activityNotFoundException;
        } catch (Exception otherException) {
            otherException.printStackTrace();

            throw otherException;
        }
    }
```

this method launch the external app I want but with no pdf file just a blank page

also I know that it is possible to get it as inputstream :

```
InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_pdf)
```

but how to open it with my specified app

is there any way to fix that

Answer (score 1):

I'm struggling with the same problem. I found that you need to set up a content provider that exposes some of your files / folders to be accessed by other apps.

Usually, android apps have their files enclosed into a sandbox that's not accessible from other apps installed on your system (some clever way to address security issues). So you need to expose them via a content provider.

Try this:

https://vshivam.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/storing-files-privately-on-android-and-opening-them-using-an-external-application/

I'm implementing it tonight... wish you luck!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will determine whether a suitable application exists on the user's device, without catching exceptions. And if exist it will open pdf file with suitable app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("path-to-document"));
intent.setType("application/pdf");

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (activities.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    // Do something else here. Maybe pop up a Dialog or Toast
}
```

Comment: thank you @vsvankhede for your suggestion but it doesn't work, in the external app, I have "An unexpected error occurred"

Comment: No. This code will not open a pdf file in assets. It's only suitable for files on the file system.